# Extend quick search box

Tags: quicksearch

We would like to extend the quick searchbox to include the fields  standard civi field 'source' as well as potentially add some of our custom fields.

Any pointers to where in the base code and examples would be hugely appreciated!

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you want to __search__ by source or do you want to add the source next to the name and email of the results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The base code for it is located at [navigation.js.tpl](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/master/templates/CRM/common/navigation.js.tpl#L40-L50) where all the menus have been listed with their search inputs.

Adding source as a search field seems to just add another line with a value as `source`.

Note: Changing core file may not be recommended as you may lose them after upgradation.

Answer (score 1):

I've developed an extension that could customize the quicksearch fields

More info here: https://civicrm.org/extensions/quicksearch